# Python json path does not exist

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

The link below returns Json data. I an getting data from several elements and there are times when the data point is just not available and the mapping does not exists. If item does not exists I want my variable set to blank so it can continue instead of erroring out and stopping.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

gameId = 220808023
url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary'
payload = {'event':gameId}

jsonData = requests.get(url,headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}, params=payload).json()

Venue = [jsonData['gameInfo']['venue']['id']]
```

Full link

http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary?event=220808023

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM It already calls `.json()` directly on the result of the call to `get`.

Comment: There at least 2 possible scenario that we get an error because of non-existence of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do 1 of 2 things:

1. Check if that key is present in that nested dictionary node
2. Use the try/except

Both options are below. The added bonus of using the try/except, is you can log the error to see why venue was stored as "N/A".

**1**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

gameId = 220808023
url = 'https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary'
payload = {'event':gameId}

jsonData = requests.get(url,headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}, params=payload).json()

if 'venue' in jsonData['gameInfo'].keys():
    venue = [jsonData['gameInfo']['venue']['id']]
else:
    venue = 'N/A'
```

**2**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd    
    
gameId = 220808023
url = 'https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary'
payload = {'event':gameId}

jsonData = requests.get(url,headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}, params=payload).json()

try:
    venue = [jsonData['gameInfo']['venue']['id']]
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e).__name__, e)
    venue = 'N/A'
```

**Output:**

```
print(venue)
N/A
```

Your other option is acquire that info from another source using the nfl season and the home team. I just used Wikipedia because it was a quick grab of teams and their home venues by season. But there may be a  better source:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

gameId = 220808023
url = 'https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary'
payload = {'event':gameId}

jsonData = requests.get(url,headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}, params=payload).json()

if 'venue' in jsonData['gameInfo'].keys():
    venue = [jsonData['gameInfo']['venue']['id']]
else:
    print('Venue no available on ESPN.\nSearching other source...')
    nfl_season = jsonData['header']['season']['year']
    for alpha in jsonData['header']['competitions'][0]['competitors']:
        if alpha['homeAway'] == 'home':
            homeTeam = alpha['team']['location'] + ' ' +  alpha ['team']['name']

            break
        
    listNflStadiums = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_home_stadiums_for_current_National_Football_League_teams')[0]
    teamStadiums = listNflStadiums[listNflStadiums[0].str.contains(homeTeam)]
    for idx, row in teamStadiums.iterrows():
        if nfl_season > int(row[4]):
            venue = row[1].split('(')[0].strip()
            break
    
    
    print(venue)
```

**Output:**

```
Venue no available on ESPN.
Searching other source...
Heinz Field
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data does not contains what you are looking for.

```
import json

import requests

gameId = 220808023
url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary'
payload = {'event': gameId}

jsonData = requests.get(
    url,
    headers={'User-agent': 'Chrome/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'},
    params=payload
).json()

# This simple print would have saved you from investigation:

print(json.dumps(jsonData, indent=4))

# > jsonData['gameInfo'] = {
# >     "attendance": 0
# > }

# This is a better way to try if a key exist in your response
try:
    gameInfo = jsonData['gameInfo']
    try:
        venue = gameInfo['venue']
        try:
            id = venue['id']
            
            Venue = id
        except KeyError:
            print('venue data doesnt contains "id"')
    except KeyError:
        print('gameInfo data doesnt contains "venue"')
except KeyError:
    print('json data doesnt contains "gameInfo"')
```

Keep in mind using PEP8 style is a good practice, and PEP8 recommand Snake case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case

Comment: I recommend using `.get()` instead of doing nested exceptions like `venue = jsonData.get("gameInfo",{}).get("venue",{}).get("id")` and check if `venue` is  `None`.

Comment: Completely agree, but he first needs to know what's below this .get().
If there is a KeyError exception then the second argument will be the value returned.
In his case, I think its better to understand the lower level ;)

Comment: you can concatenate `.get()` returning a default empty dict until it arrives to the deeper level. In that way s/he can control if the att exists in every level. `.get("att1", {}).get("att1_1",{}).get("att1_1_1")`

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

gameId = 220808023
url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary'
payload = {'event':gameId}

jsonData = requests.get(url,headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}, params=payload).json()

venue = jsonData.get("gameInfo",{}).get("venue",{}).get("id","")
# .get(att,default) accepts a second parameter which is the returned value if cannot find the dict attribute. If you set it with blank text, venue will value empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the dictionary has a specific key by `key in dic`.
So, *in principle*, you can avoid `KeyError` by checking the existence of the key before querying the value for the key to the dictionary.

In order to avoid ugly nested if statements, you can define a wrapper class that checks the key existence when queried. The point is in python, accessing values by `dic[key]` is translated to calling the `dic.__getitem__(key)`.

Example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

gameId = 220808023
url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary'
payload = {'event': gameId}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers={
                        'User-agent': 'Chrome/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}, params=payload).json()


class MaybeDict:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not self.val:
            return MaybeDict(None)
        if not key in self.val:
            return MaybeDict(None)
        return MaybeDict(self.val[key])


response = MaybeDict(jsonData)
print(response["gameInfo"]["venue"]["id"].val)
```